# Convert PHP variable "11:00 AM" to MySQL time format

Tags: php, mysql, time

Trying to convert standard time variable from form input to TIME format acceptable for MySQL INSERT. I might be going about it all wrong and could use some help. I've read through the MySQL TIME functions and PHP TIME functions but haven't found a solution yet.

Here's what I've tried as an example:

```
<?php
$time_input = '11:00 AM';

$strtotime = strtotime($time_input);

$mysql_time = date('H:m:s',$strtotime);

echo "<p>time_input: $time_input</p>";
echo "<p>strtotime: $strtotime</p>";
echo "<p>mysql_time: $mysql_time</p>";
?>
```

The result is changing the time to 11:08:00 (not sure where the 8 minutes is coming from):

```
time_input: 11:00 AM

strtotime: 1344438000

mysql_time: 11:08:00
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: The 8 is because it's the 8th month: August.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) will do this for you:

```
$time_input = '11:00 AM';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i A', $time_input);
$formatted = $date->format( 'H:i:s');
```

I typically avoid `strtotime()` when possible as it can be somewhat unpredictable.

You can see it work in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/hrIOLp).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on using DateTime! I'm going to give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

`m` is the format for the month with leading zeros (August, i.e. 08), you want `i` (minutes with leading zeros):

```
$mysql_time = date('H:i:s',$strtotime);
```

[PHP date docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)